# Куда делись ночные вопросы?

Tags: обсуждение, вопросы, статистика

Смотрю на количество заданных в последние 4 часа перед концом суток по Гринвичу вопросов и вижу, что в апреле и мае их количество уменьшилось. С чем это может быть связано?

Запрос: https://data.stackexchange.com/ru/revision/1055686/1303411/#graph

```
select
  DATEFROMPARTS(DATEPART(yyyy, CreationDate), DATEPART(mm, CreationDate), 1) as Month,
  sum(IIF(DATEPART(hh, CreationDate) >= 20, 1, 0)) as [20+],
  sum(IIF(DATEPART(hh, CreationDate) >= 21, 1, 0)) as [21+],
  sum(IIF(DATEPART(hh, CreationDate) >= 22, 1, 0)) as [22+],
  sum(IIF(DATEPART(hh, CreationDate) >= 23, 1, 0)) as [23+]
from Posts
where PostTypeId = 1 and DATEPART(yyyy, CreationDate) >= 2016
group by DATEFROMPARTS(DATEPART(yyyy, CreationDate), DATEPART(mm, CreationDate), 1)
order by 1
```

Результат:

```
Month     20+   21+   22+   23+
-------------------------------
2016-01   420   276   165   83
2016-02   515   335   173   70
2016-03   473   309   168   56
2016-04   410   230   113   46
2016-05   447   269   140   59
2016-06   380   232   114   36
2016-07   410   238   120   56
2016-08   397   247   124   52
2016-09   421   244   131   48
2016-10   500   322   169   57
2016-11   584   374   199   81
2016-12   551   361   187   68
2017-01   602   388   226   95
2017-02   563   367   188   62
2017-03   604   369   209   70
2017-04   528   308   161   63
2017-05   589   349   158   60
2017-06   477   297   142   47
2017-07   503   319   181   74
2017-08   457   282   153   55
2017-09   443   263   134   56
2017-10   553   341   182   74
2017-11   661   425   239   91
2017-12   675   444   241   85
2018-01   696   443   229   97
2018-02   590   362   183   70
2018-03   697   423   210   76
2018-04   501   275   135   50
2018-05   616   364   186   83
2018-06   571   351   185   75
2018-07   564   329   180   70
2018-08   515   304   155   56
2018-09   527   339   175   61
2018-10   577   329   184   79
2018-11   675   423   216   88
2018-12   674   435   234   78
2019-01   632   395   226   95
2019-02   574   357   192   77
2019-03   642   388   204   77
2019-04   490   298   135   51
2019-05   322   193   100   27
```

График:

[image: График]

Если посмотреть на апрельское число вопросов и найти ближайшее, которое его не превосходит, то получится апрель прошлого года и сентябрь 17го:

```
Month     20+   21+   22+   23+
-------------------------------
2017-09   443   263   134   56
2018-04   501   275   135   50
2019-04   490   298   135   51
2019-05   322   193   100   27
```

Да и май уже заканчивается, а видно что там тоже негусто.

Какие мысли, почему так?

А то не получается в конце дня добрать до 200, а раньше получалось...

Comment: Это не то чтобы ответ, но количество вопросов вообще падает второй месяц. Добавил среднее за 4 часа на график: https://data.stackexchange.com/ru/query/1055702#graph

Comment: @defaultlocale, май ещё не кончился, а апрель - вроде не упало. Там 908, а значения меньше были в декабре и январе - вполне в пределах колебаний всё.

Comment: @defaultlocale там каждый год есть небольшое падение в апреле-мае. Какая-то сезонность, может из-за весны народ больше времени на улице начинает проводить :)

Comment: @PashaPash, с 23:00 до 3:00 по Москве?

Comment: @Qwertiy нет, по общему количеству сообщений

Comment: @PashaPash надо проверить эту теорию на южном полушарии. Должно быть октябрь-ноябрь.